# List está sendo preenchida mas as propriedades estão null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Olá, 
pessoal estou utilizando o seguinte método no C# :

```
        public ActionResult Gravar(int pCodigo, string pDestino, int pRespDestino, int pOs, int pProjeto, string pEstabelecimento, string pObs, int pPim, string pAlmoxarifado, List<RequisicaoItem> pItens)
    {
        var elaborador = new intranetRepository.Adm.Repository.UsuarioRepository().CarregaUsuarioCompletoPorCodigo(new Usuario() { Id = new MVCUtilities().ObtemCodigoUsuario().GetValueOrDefault() });            

        var requisicao = new Requisicao()
        {
            Codigo = pCodigo,
            Destino = new CentroCusto() { Id = pDestino},
            RespDestino = new Usuario() { Id = pRespDestino },
            Uf = new CentroCusto() { Id = elaborador.Funcionario.CentroCusto.Id },
            RespUf = new intranetRepository.Adm.Repository.UsuarioRepository().CarregaUsuarioPorLogin(elaborador.Funcionario.Secao.Responsavel.UsuarioIntranet), 
            Os = pOs,
            Elaborador = new Usuario() { Id = elaborador.Id, Nome = elaborador.Nome },
            Projeto = new intranetRepository.Projeto.Model.Projeto() { Id = pProjeto} ,
            Estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento() { Sigla = pEstabelecimento},
            Observacao = pObs,
            Pim = new intranetRepository.Pim.Model.Pim() { Id = pPim },
            Almoxarifado = new Almoxarifado() { Sigla = pAlmoxarifado },
            Sistema = new Sistema() { Id = 2 },
            Itens = null
        };
        var retorno = new RequisicaoRepository().Gravar(requisicao);
        return Json(retorno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Esse método, que está no controller, é chamado pelo Javascript, através do seguinte código :

```
$('#btnGravar').on('click', function () {

var itens = [];    
$('#divRequisicaoItem table tbody tr').each(function () {

    var item = {

        Localizacao : 'DGT222'
    };
    itens.push(item);
});

var param = {

    pCodigo: "0",
    pDestino: $("#ddlDestino").val(),
    pRespDestino: $("#ddlResponsavel").val(),
    pOs: "0",
    pProjeto: $("#txbProjetoCodigo").val() === '' ? "0" : $("txbProjetoCodigo").val(),
    pEstabelecimento: $("#ddlEstabelecimento").val(),
    pObs: $("#txbObservacao").val(),
    pPim: $("#txbPimCodigo").val() === '' ? "0" : $("#txbPimCodigo").val(),
    pAlmoxarifado: $("#ddlRetirarNo").val(),
    pItens: itens        
};

if ($('#formRequisicao').valid()) {

    if ($('#divRequisicaoItem table tbody tr').length >= 1) {

        $.ajax({

            url: '/Req/Requisicao/Gravar',
            data: param,
            beforeSend: function () {

                adicionarLoadingTela();
            }
        }).done(function (result) {


        });

    } else {
        var mensagem = {
            Tipo: 'A',
            Mensagem: 'Você precisa inserir pelo menos um item na requisição.'
        };
        exibirMensagem(mensagem, 100);
    }
}
```

});

Só que não consigo entender, por que o último parâmetro ( List pItens )  do método gravar vem com a quantidade de itens, mas as propriedades dele estão vindo null.

A classe é essa :

```
    public class RequisicaoItem
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Ordem Ordem { get; set; }
    public Deposito Deposito { get; set; }
    public string Localizacao { get; set; }
    public decimal Qtde { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoComplementar { get; set; }
    public decimal SaldoUju { get; set; }
    public decimal SaldoUsi { get; set; }
    public decimal SaldoUfl { get; set; }
    public decimal SaldoUfa { get; set; }
    public decimal SaldoUcb { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O binding dum array/lista de elementos através da query string tem que seguir uma regra especial. No seu caso o parametro chama-se `pItens`.

A sua query string tem que ter o seguinte formato:

```
pItens[0].SaldoUju=valor&pItens[0].SaldoUsi=valor&...&  
pItens[1].SaldoUju=valor&pItens[1].SaldoUsi=valor&...
```

Ou seja Voce tem que preencher todas as propriedades explicitamente para cada elemento do array,

O melhor mesmo é alterar o seu método para aceitar uma requisicao http com método Post e receber os valores no formato `application\json` no corpo da requisicao. O binding será feito automáticamente e os clientes nao tem que construir uma query string gigantesca e com um formato complicado.

[Fonte](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)